# Does a sequence of coin-tosses a.s. have a subsequence on which the remainder of the sequence can be identified with the position in the sequence?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Let $(X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ be an i.i.d. sequence of $\{0,1\}$-valued random variables $X_n \sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(\frac{1}{2})$, i.e. a sequence of independent tosses of a fair coin.

> Does there exist a (non-random) Borel-measurable function $h \colon \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}} \to \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ such that
> $$ \mathbb{P}(\exists\,\text{infinitely many } k \geq 0 \text{ s.t. }h((X_{k+n})_{n \geq 0})=k ) = 1 \, \text{?} $$

Comment: It seems to me we can  just interpret the sequence as the binary representation of a number between 0 and 1, and let h(X) be the reciprocal of this number, rounded down to an integer.

Comment: @JohanWästlund Nice - is the proof obvious that your $h$ fulfils the requirement?

Comment: @JohanWästlund But at least, I guess there should exist some monotone transformation of your $h$ that works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a function $h$ does not exist.

Indeed, given a  Borel-measurable function $h \colon \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}} \to \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0},$ define for each $k \ge 0$ the events
$$A_k=\Bigl\{h \Bigl((X_{n})_{n \geq 0}\Bigr)=k \Bigr\}$$
and
$$B_k=\Bigl\{h \Bigl((X_{k+n})_{n \geq 0}\Bigr)=k \Bigr\} \,.$$
Clearly,
$$\mathbb{P}(A_k)=\mathbb{P}(B_k) \;\; \mbox{for every} \; k \ge 0.
$$
The $A_k$ are disjoint events that partition the probabiility space, so
$$ 1=\sum_{k \ge 0} \mathbb{P}(A_k)=\sum_{k \ge 0}\mathbb{P}(B_k) \,.
$$
Therefore, by the (first) Borel-Cantelli lemma,
$$ \mathbb{P}(\exists\,\text{infinitely many } k \geq 0 \text{ s.t. }h((X_{k+n})_{n \geq 0})=k ) = 0 \,.
$$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma